# Is @xxforms:format deprecated?

Tags: orbeon, xforms

The extension `xxforms:format` is still supported in Orbeon 4.7 according to [this page](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-other-extensions#TOC-The-xxforms:format-attribute).

However: it stopped working for me. Is this a documentation bug or an Orbeon 4.7 bug?

Code that worked in 3.9:

```
<xforms:output
    ref="$effectiveDate"
    xxforms:format="
        if (. castable as xs:dateTime)
        then replace(format-dateTime(xs:dateTime(.),'[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01] [H01]:[m01]:[s01]', (), (), ()),' 00:00:00','')
        else (.)"/>
```

Comment: I tried your example and it works for me. Could it be an issue unrelated to `xxf:format`?

Comment: What kind of issue would I be looking for? Testing on my local machine with Orbeon 4.7 ignores xxforms:format. The production machines are on Orbeon 3.9 and display as documented/expected. The underlying forms and css are identical.

Comment: I am not sure. Can you try a simple example, maybe just `<xf:output ref="first-name" xxforms:format="concat(., 'bar')"/>` and see if something like that works? Can you also try to display the `$effectiveDate`, maybe with `<xf:output value="name($effectiveDate)"/>`, to make sure that `$effectiveDate` is there?